# cat vs. opening a readonly file

Tags: c, linux-kernel, embedded-linux, cat, spi

tl;dr - when I'm doing a cat of an infinitely long file, everything's great, but when I use C's "open" even without reading of the same file, everything fails. Why might that happen? How can I make it not happen?

---

I'm developing on the Digi ME9210, which stars a small embedded linux O/S but has other useful things like an SPI driver.

What I would like to do, ultimately, is to read an SPI device at a consistently-spaced 10k samples per second. The example SPI driver that came with the device offers the ability to do an SPI read from userland by use of the ioctl function. Unfortunately, when looking at the timing, the reads weren't consistent at all - usleep and other delay functions gave inconsistent results, and even if I just used a tight loop like `while (true) { sample_spi(); }`, the spacing was inconsistent.

I decided to look into editing the kernel driver. I'm able to get a very reliable periodic interrupt by editing the proper registers, and I'm able to set up a routine so I get that sweet SPI reading on every interrupt. Great. For debugging purposes, I said "I'll also just see if it can even run at 1kHz, rather than expecting the full 10kHZ"

In the shell, to check my timing, I ran

`cat /dev/spidev1.0`

which does an infinite read. The SPI reads come out looking mostly periodic, with an occasional slip (three or five ms rather than 1 ms). I assumed this was something to do with how the cat utility has to periodically dump to stream. So I wrote a small C program that looks like this:

`int f = open("/dev/spidev1.0", O_RDONLY);
// some time-wasting logic here
close(f);`

When I run that, I get maybe ten SPI reads, and then the whole Linux machine stops responding until I do a reset.

What's up with this? Why does `cat`ting a file work when opening it leads to a freeze state? What is cat doing differently? I'd have assumed that cat looked a lot like "open the file, read it, print it, and close it". The C code is doing 50% of that, and not even the hard 50%.

Things I've looked at

1. **Maybe your interrupt isn't actually sustainable** - if I just update a counter instead of performing an SPI read, the interrupt goes on forever very cheerfully.
2. **Maybe C will just never work like cat** - if I drop my interrupt speed to 20Hz, the C code and cat work just the same as each other.
3. **Maybe cat is just perfect** - if I boost my interrupt speed to 10kHz, cat will read for about 5ms before it freezes. The c code will do a few reads, with wildly different spacing, before freezing.

Comment: You can see cat's source code, if that will be any help. Or at least the version of GNU cat available here - http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/coreutils.git/plain/src/cat.c. Of course, it would be best if you could examine the source of the specific version of `cat` for your linux version. Note they use `fdadvise (input_desc, 0, 0, FADVISE_SEQUENTIAL);`, maybe that is significant.

Comment: In case you are able to lock the entire kernel using your code, my guess is you are looking at the problem from the wrong side: You don't need to fix the application to work like `cat`, but rather your driver to not lock the machine.

Comment: Without knowing how your code is reading, and what the driver might be doing (as in handling for open, read, poll, etc.), it'll be difficult to help. and as @tofro said, userland programs shouldn't be able to lock up the kernel.

Comment: Which `cat` are you comparing it to? There's many implementations. [here's a couple](https://gist.github.com/pete/665971)

Comment: @tofro (and Hasturkun) - thanks, that's actually a very reasonable suggestion that I ovelooked. I'd assumed that somehow what I was doing in userland was pushing the kernel into an undefined state, but that raises the question of why I let such a state exist to begin with. I'll start re-examining the kernel before looking too much more at cat.

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem - d'oh, I foolishly assumed cat was monolithic. It's the BusyBox implementation. Thanks for the pointer!

Comment: Wrt your second possibility: what magic language do you think `cat` is written in which unlocks features not available in C? :-) (As evident from the links, most `cat`s are C.)

Comment: Well, `cat(1)` is actually written in C, so your assumption must be wrong.  And the major part of the kernel is also written in C, so it's difficult to imagine something hidden that cannot be made in C, but `cat(1)` solves quite elegantly.

Comment: @rici - Yeah I was pretty sure that cat was written in c, which is what was making the different behaviors so confusing. Like the previous commenters said, though, I probably want to write a driver that doesn't lock at all, rather than one that doesn't lock if I do something cat-like (whatever cat-like means)

Answer (score 0):

You should try writing your own `cat`-like program to test out your open, read, and close code.  Then add the other processing to that program until something breaks.

If you find that your `cat`-like program doesn't work then

From a command line type:

```
strace -o spi_cat_trace.txt cat /dev/spidev1.0
less spi_cat_trace.txt
```

and then try to work out how your `cat`-like program differs from what `cat` does in reading the file.

Comment: shouldn't it be better to look at the actual `cat(1)` source code?

Comment: If you look at the source code to `cat` you will see stuff lots of code that may not actually execute.  You'll have to sort through the decisions that that code makes to find out what it actually does.  Using `strace` you get to see just what actually happens without worrying about how `cat` decided that it would happen.  After viewing `strace` you might see some things that are puzzling and lead you to investigate the code, though.

Comment: ... but don't look at the gnu cat, which probably is far too complicated.  Look at the BSD cat, which probably is clearer.  FreeBSD cat is only one source file 362 lines long.